# Bootstrap 3 navbar below logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm new to Bootstrap 3 and I'm still learning. Till now I managed to make an simple navbar with logos and links. I'm now trying to have my logo above and my navigationbar below the logo. I've used HTML breaks, but that only is spacing my bar downwords.

The code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Super Signals</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Targets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

This is what I have now:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: initial;` to the navbar-header class

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `float: none` or `float: initial` which will remove the left float that is currently in effect.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see here. It's a problem of telling the browser where you want to position.

**1. Use CSS**

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

**2. Using quick positioning classes**

position-static,

position-relative,

position-absolute,

position-fixed,

position-sticky,

**3. Float**

float: none, float: initial

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and style your h1 tag as your requirement

```
<div class="container"><h1>Super Signals</h1></div>    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Targets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Any problem or question just ask in comment below my answer